# Systemd becomes unresponsive

Tags: systemd

Within three weeks, on two of my Ubuntu 20.04LTS servers `systemd` has suddenly become unresponsive.
Symptoms:

- All `systemctl` commands for controlling services or accessing logs fail with error messages:

```
Failed to retrieve unit state: Connection timed out
Failed to get properties: Connection timed out
```

- `systemd` does not heed the signal from `logrotate` for reopening its log, continuing to write to the renamed log file `/var/log/syslog.1` while the newly created `/var/log/syslog` remains empty.
- Lots of zombie processes accumulating from cronjobs and system management tasks, ie. PID 1 systemd neglects its duty of reaping orphaned processes.
- Running services continue to run normally but starting or stopping services is no longer possible as even the legacy scripts in `/etc/init.d` redirect to the non-functional `systemctl`.
- Nothing unusual in the logs except the `Connection timed out` messages from attempted interactions with `systemd`.

The commonly proposed corrective measures:

- `systemctl daemon-reexec`
- `kill -TERM 1`
- removing `/run/systemd/system/session-*.scope.d`

do not fix the problem.
The only remedy is to reboot the entire system, which is of course both disruptive and problematic for a server on the other side of the globe.

The same problem occurred with Ubuntu 16.04LTS about once per month in a population of about 100 servers. It is much less frequent since the upgrade to 20.04LTS, but not completely gone. Of the two servers that have been hit since 20.04LTS, one had already been hit when it was still running 16.04LTS.

Questions:

- What are possible causes for that sort of `systemd` malfunction?
- How can I diagnose this further?
- Is there a less disruptive way to recover from an unresponsive `systemd` than to reboot?

Comment: Can you upgrade? preferably to 20.04 LTS? That version of systemd is rather old at this point. As is that whole system.

Comment: DIfficult to say what exactly the problem. I think moving to 20.04 won't solve the problem without understanding cause. I think you should start searching for information about zombie processes for your version of the cron. Maybe there was a bag, or maybe there is a problem with processes that cron runs.

Comment: The accumulating zombie processes are most certainly not cron's fault. It's part of regular operation of cron to spawn processes which then get inherited by process ID 1 in a process called daemonizing. It's the job of the program occupying process ID 1 to reap those processes so that they don't become zombies, and it's a sign of serious malfunction of systemd if it isn't able to fulfil this basic job anymore. So I don't believe investigating cron will lead anywhere.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Meanwhile we have upgraded to 20.04LTS and the problem has reoccurred. Will update the question.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved? I am facing the same problem on my Debian 11 server.

Comment: No, the issue hasn't been resolved and I don't see any progress in the matter. I am learning to live with systemd as an additional source of trouble.

Answer (score 2):

this is a very old question, but I hope it can save someone else time.

I had a identical problem, some zombies and systemctl respond any request with a timeout.
As expected the problem was to remove the daemons. At least on our case the solution was:

```
telinit u
systemctl daemon-reexec
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: @TilmanSchmidt, today we faced the same issue; there was like 14 defunct process, everything was sluggish, almost restarting the server...

right after systemctl daemon-reload, all zombies "died" systemctl became responsive and the system too... not sure if you need all 3 commands, but it did work again for us

Comment: Apparently my issue is different from yours. On 95 servers distributed worldwide I encounter the issue about once a month on average. In none of these cases did any of these commands have a noticeable effect. I still hope it will disappear with the upgrade to 20.04 which is in the pipeline but pandemically delayed.

Comment: "I still hope it will disappear with the upgrade to 20.04" - it didn't. Just had two more occurrences with 20.04LTS, see updated question. again `telinit u` and `systemctl daemon-reexec` didn't help, only hard reset (`echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger`) did.